# Reference tables that are not explicitly defined

Tags: blazor

I've got the following entities defined.

```
public class Piece : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int NumOfCopies { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPerformed { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool ScoreYesNo { get; set; } = false;
    public string URL { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Notes { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Publisher? Publisher { get; set; }
    public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
    public List<Theme>? Themes { get; set; } = new List<Theme>();
}

public class Theme : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Piece>? Pieces { get; set; } = new List<Piece>();
}

public class Publisher : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Piece>? Pieces { get; set; } = new List<Piece>();
}
```

Here's the relivant parts of my DataContext.

```
public DbSet<Piece> Pieces { get; set; }
public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Theme> Themes { get; set; }
```

I'm using dotnet ef migrations to generate the DB structure and it's creating the following Tables.

- Pieces
- Themes
- Publishers
- PieceTheme

I have this code in my Services in my API.

```
public async Task<List<Piece>> CreatePiece(Piece piece)
{
    _dataContext.Pieces.Add(piece);
    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return await GetAllPieces();
}
```

How can I implement code to add and remove Contributors to a given Piece?